# Matching edge in Neo4j Cypher is really slow

Tags: performance, neo4j, cypher

I have a database with 500K nodes and 700K relationships. I created 500 additional relationships with a new type`DummyEdge` with `edge_id` attributes from "1" to "500". Now I want to query and modify these relationships. Running a query
`MATCH ()-[e:DummyEdge {edge_id:"123"}]->() SET e.property="value"` is really slow, it takes around 300ms, so if I run 500 such queries, it takes around 2-3 minutes. I also called `CREATE INDEX ON :DummyEdge(edge_id)` but it didn't speed up the query execution.

Is there any way to make such bulk relationship modification faster?

Comment: If you add your start- or end-label it will be much faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[CREATE INDEX](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/schema/index/#schema-index-create-a-single-property-index) creates an index for **nodes**, so such an index would make no difference in the performance of your query.

Since your `MATCH` pattern, `()-[e:DummyEdge {edge_id:"123"}]->()`, provided no information about the end nodes, neo4j has to scan every relationship in the DB to find the ones you want. That is why your query is so slow.

It would be much more efficient if (as @ MichaelHunger stated) your query provided useful information (like a label, or an indexed label/property pair) for either of the nodes in your `MATCH` pattern. That would help neo4j narrow down the number of relationships that need to be scanned. As an example, let's state that the start node must have the `Foo` label:

```
MATCH (:Foo)-[e:DummyEdge {edge_id:"123"}]->()
SET e.property="value"
```

With the above query, neo4j would only have to look at the outgoing relationships of `Foo` nodes, which is much faster since neo4j can quickly find nodes with a given label (or index).

*Now, neo4j also supports [full-text schema indexes](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/schema/index/#schema-index-fulltext-search), which do support relationship indexes. However, those kinds of indexes require much more effort on your part, and may be overkill for your use case.*

Comment: Thank you! The number of `DummyEdge` relationships is small, and it would be fast to scan just these relationships, but I guess Neo4j is still scanning every relationship?

Answer (score 0):

There are now relationship - indexes that should spee up your operation massively.

https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/indexes-for-search-performance/#administration-indexes-create-a-single-property-b-tree-index-for-relationships